How to copy all the data from a CSV (starting from row 1) over to an existing Excel file?
My script copies data from a CSV file located in a local folder over to a file located in a shared drive folder.  The problem I am having is that the CSV does not have headers, it is all data which means that starting from row 1 column A there is valid data but after running the script it skips row 1 entirely leaving out data. Can someone assist in updating my script so that it includes row 1?
import pandas as pd
import os

csv_file_path = r'C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\file1.csv'
excel_file_path = r'S:\noWhere\noWhereAgain\file2.xlsx'

csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

if os.path.exists(excel_file_path):
    excel_data = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)
    
    last_row_index = excel_data.last_valid_index()
    
    start_row = last_row_index + 2 if last_row_index is not None else 0
    with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        csv_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=start_row, index=False, header=False)

else:
    csv_data.to_excel(excel_file_path, index=False)


Here is what I have tried
 csv_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=0, index=False, header=True)

and
 csv_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=start_row, index=False, header=True)

Unfortunately, both did not work.
Any assistance will be appreciated.

Check out the other parameters in read_csv. Then try header=0.

@tdelaney read_csv  docs you linked says "Explicitly pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names." and "If the file contains a header row, then you should explicitly pass header=0 to override the column names" which indicate we Don't need header=0 explicitly since we don't have header in file. And since "if no names are passed the behavior is identical to header=0" so we already have set header=0. Seems like that param can't just create placeholder col names.

nvm header=None do work, idk why it's not documented..

when I tried header=None that did not work for me.

Just pass header=None to read_csv!
Actually non of the read_csv document section about header param mentions it for some reason... but feature is there.
import pathlib

import pandas as pd


data = """
0.7319,0.1979,0.4434,0.1862,0.9935
0.9294,0.1011,0.9114,0.1939,0.838
0.2386,0.1529,0.8174,0.3015,0.2691
0.6291,0.8105,0.5586,0.5512,0.3286
0.8575,0.0055,0.0441,0.2989,0.0135
0.331,0.0968,0.89,0.8253,0.2725
0.7356,0.8136,0.5955,0.0051,0.7264
0.6151,0.7336,0.275,0.5213,0.47
0.9855,0.9211,0.1162,0.0454,0.838
0.4032,0.9121,0.8177,0.519,0.5087
"""

ROOT = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
FILE = ROOT / "data.csv"

# just writing data file so code run without any external file
FILE.write_text(data)


# this way read_csv infer column names from first row
csv_data_0 = pd.read_csv(FILE)

# this doesn't do a thing. Already header=0 is default as we have no name to pass.
csv_data_1 = pd.read_csv(FILE, header=0)

# this way read_csv does not infer column names. no header so header=None.
csv_data_2 = pd.read_csv(FILE, header=None)


print(csv_data_0, csv_data_1, csv_data_2, sep="\n\n")

   0.7319  0.1979  0.4434  0.1862  0.9935
0  0.9294  0.1011  0.9114  0.1939  0.8380
1  0.2386  0.1529  0.8174  0.3015  0.2691
2  0.6291  0.8105  0.5586  0.5512  0.3286
3  0.8575  0.0055  0.0441  0.2989  0.0135
4  0.3310  0.0968  0.8900  0.8253  0.2725
5  0.7356  0.8136  0.5955  0.0051  0.7264
6  0.6151  0.7336  0.2750  0.5213  0.4700
7  0.9855  0.9211  0.1162  0.0454  0.8380
8  0.4032  0.9121  0.8177  0.5190  0.5087

   0.7319  0.1979  0.4434  0.1862  0.9935
0  0.9294  0.1011  0.9114  0.1939  0.8380
1  0.2386  0.1529  0.8174  0.3015  0.2691
2  0.6291  0.8105  0.5586  0.5512  0.3286
3  0.8575  0.0055  0.0441  0.2989  0.0135
4  0.3310  0.0968  0.8900  0.8253  0.2725
5  0.7356  0.8136  0.5955  0.0051  0.7264
6  0.6151  0.7336  0.2750  0.5213  0.4700
7  0.9855  0.9211  0.1162  0.0454  0.8380
8  0.4032  0.9121  0.8177  0.5190  0.5087

        0       1       2       3       4
0  0.7319  0.1979  0.4434  0.1862  0.9935
1  0.9294  0.1011  0.9114  0.1939  0.8380
2  0.2386  0.1529  0.8174  0.3015  0.2691
3  0.6291  0.8105  0.5586  0.5512  0.3286
4  0.8575  0.0055  0.0441  0.2989  0.0135
5  0.3310  0.0968  0.8900  0.8253  0.2725
6  0.7356  0.8136  0.5955  0.0051  0.7264
7  0.6151  0.7336  0.2750  0.5213  0.4700
8  0.9855  0.9211  0.1162  0.0454  0.8380
9  0.4032  0.9121  0.8177  0.5190  0.5087

You can see csv_data_2 correctly generate dummy columns while csv_data_1 and csv_data_0 just infer from first line.
